# Question about typing and strange characters

Tags: discussion, voting, typesetting

Ok I am almost a month old user here, so basically I am completely new to using mathematical symbols and characters in this site. I always type my question completely and keep editing constantly so that nothing makes difficult for the reader and no strange character appears from copying and pasting. And, if I still make mistakes, then please correct me in the polite way. But, my question is instead of pointing out my mistakes, why do some people assume I am using something different and giving me down vote for that? Again, I am not a pro and people learn from as they go. So, Do you just give down votes for question that has some typing errors?

Comment: I assume you're talking about [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1167173/2). It is indeed full of strange characters (before it was revised) - I don't know what technical issue is causing that - however, it does seem unreasonable to me to downvote in this case; the question seems fine, and the extraneous characters aren't obscuring what you're saying. Given the trivial nature of the error in the post, I don't see why three users left comments to this effect instead of just editing your post to remove the strangeness.

Comment: (I didn't downvote the post.)  Right now the post is still filled with "strange characters" for me.  For example, after "here it goes: h" there are two strange characters.  @Meelo, I can't edit it because I don't know what the strange characters mean.  Perhaps that's why the others didn't edit it also.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bbB89.png) is what it looks like to me, right now.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Ah! That's wholly different from how it looks to me. For me, it displays as if those characters simply didn't exist (and the earlier revisions just have a couple, different boxes which are clearly extraneous). That would explain why others didn't edit.

Comment: From your comment I take it that the strange characters can just be removed.  I've edited the question now to remove them.

Comment: @Joel Reyes Noche thank you so much for editing my question. I have no idea where those strange characters came from? I guess there were some technical issues even though I didn't see them on my computer.

Comment: Most likely, you are using unicode characters that are not available on most other computers.  If you're using greek letters (or similar), replace them with their TeX counterpart (e.g. `\alpha`).

Comment: The odd characters (`U+10FC03` - `U+10FC07`) are in the unicode "Supplementary Private Use B" range. They are available for private use, but have no inter-application definition as printable characters.

Comment: Do you know how these characters get there in the first place? Or absent this could you perhaps tell how you compose your posts? Especially from where do you copy-paste.  So, that a solution could be propose to prevent this. Perhaps just do not copy-paste or do so via a "clean" intermediate step like a simple text-editor.

Comment: That's the strange part. I was just typing as usual don't know how/where those characters came from. Weird huh!

Comment: @robjohn I don't even know what those "Supplementary Private Use B" characters mean. And, the funny thing is while you guys were seeing some funny looking characters, I was seeing nothing strange, which is why I couldn't tell what to remove or edit.

Comment: In view of the comment thread, I'd say an [edit] of the main post to change the scope is due; after all, nonuniformity in displaying the question is the root problem here.

Comment: But, the thing is how'd you edit something if you don't exactly see what to edit for?

Comment: Please post a picture of what it looks like on your side.

Comment: But, it's already been edited. How can I even find the original post though I am trying...

Comment: @abcd1234: [the link](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1167173/2) that Meelo posted gets you to the second revision, which has the odd characters. It has been edited, so you don't need to do anything about the second revision.

Comment: @robjohn: I’ve seen this phenomenon once before. There was a question a while back in whose title some of us saw a couple of unrecognized characters while others, including the poster, did not. Simply removing them solved the problem: the boxes disappeared for those of us who had seen them, and there was no change for those who had not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It is a matter of the fonts installed in a user's computer. If a font is installed that claims to know that glyph, the computer will render it. Otherwise, a substitute is used; often a glyph with the unicode glyph code displayed.

Comment: @robjohn: I realize that; the (minor) oddity is that it was apparently invisible when rendered, as its deletion was invisible to those who hadn’t seen the unicode glyph code.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: to me, this indicates that either they had a font with that character defined as non-printable, or the substitute glyph on their system is non-printable.

Comment: What program are you using to type your questions/answers? You really should just learn $\LaTeX$ and be typing it out by hand. This will avoid any strange characters being inserted.

Comment: I am learning it now.